# Netbeans platform application Topcomponents location

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

In my NetBeans Platform based application, I have two top components with default editor location :

```
@TopComponent.Description(
            preferredID = "AddResourcesTopComponent",
            persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS
    )
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "editor", openAtStartup = true)

@TopComponent.Description(
            preferredID = "ViewerTopComponent",
            persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS
    )
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "editor", openAtStartup = false )
```

and I have explorer topcomponent :

```
 @TopComponent.Description(
        preferredID = "PackageContentsTopComponent",
        persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS
)
 @TopComponent.Registration(mode = "explorer", openAtStartup = true)
```

and the problem is that :

1. Viewer TopComponent that has `openAtStartup = false` opens when I
   start the application but the PackageContents TopComponent that has
   `openAtStartup = true`don't open when I start the application.
2. When I open PackageContents (using Window->PackageContents) it opens
   on the editor location instead of explorer location.

any help? very thanks